# How to get rid of the zeros at the end of sorted integers

Tags: java, sorting

My code is working but it gives me unnecessary number and I don't know how to get rid of them.Please any suggestion would be highly appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


 public class ArraySort1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Scanner inputFile; 
  inputFile = new Scanner(new File("arrayex1.txt"));
  PrintWriter outputFile;
outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("sorted.txt"));

      /* Declare the array */

int[] numbers = new int[10000];
int index = 0;

      int temp, smallest, smallest_index;

      /* Read the first number */
      numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();

      while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
        index++;
        }
// Local variable
int swValue;

// Display menu graphics
System.out.println("============================");
System.out.println("|   MENU SELECTION DEMO    |");
System.out.println("============================");
System.out.println("| Options:                 |");
System.out.println("|        1. Selection Sort |");
System.out.println("|        2.  Bubble Sort   |");
System.out.println("|        3. Exit           |");
System.out.println("============================");
swValue = Keyin.inInt(" Select option: ");

// Switch construct
switch (swValue) {
case 1:
  System.out.println(" Selection Sort Starting....");
  for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {

      smallest = numbers[i];
      smallest_index = i;

      for (int j = i + 1; j < index; j++) {

        if (numbers[j] < smallest) { 
              smallest = numbers[j];
              smallest_index = j;
          }
      }

      /* If needed switch numbers[i] and numbers[smallest_index] */

      if (numbers[i] != numbers[smallest_index]) {

          temp = numbers[i];
          numbers[i] = numbers[smallest_index];
          numbers[smallest_index] = temp;
      }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {          
    System.out.print (numbers[i] + " ");
          outputFile.print (numbers[i] + " ");
      }

      inputFile.close();
      outputFile.close();



  break;
case 2:
 //2 System.out.println("Bubble Sort Sorting 2 selected");

    //int i = 0, t=0;
    boolean swapped = true;

    while(swapped){

    swapped = false;

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < index  - 1; i1++){
        smallest = numbers[i1];
        smallest_index = i1;

    if(numbers[i1] > numbers[i1 + 1]){
    swapped = true;
    int tmp = numbers[i1];
    numbers[i1] = numbers[i1 + 1];
    numbers[i1 + 1] = tmp;
    } 
    } 

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++){
   System.out.print(numbers[i1] + "\t");
    } 
   System.out.println();

    }




 break;

case 3:
  System.out.println("Exit selected");
  break;
default:
  System.out.println("Invalid selection");
  break; // This break is not really necessary
   }
 }

}
```

If I Select option 2 : Bubble sort I get

```
1   2   4   1   5   7   9   56  67  0   0   0
1   2   4   5   7   9   56  67   0               0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   1   2   4   5   7   9   56  67  0
```

Please the code where I have problem is the Bubble sort.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array has the length 10000.

```
int[] numbers = new int[10000];
```

This is the way you generate the output when choosing 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
```

You only print up to `index` (which is the amount of integers you read from the file).

When you choose option 2, this is the way you generate the output:

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++){
```

where `numbers.length` means every element of the array. I'm not writing the solution now, because I think you should be able to solve it yourself from here.

Comment: Thanks @jlordo i have been able to remove the zero... how can i be to be able to print only the sorted array. I look forward to your reply...

Comment: If you would format your code nicely (indentation) you would see that the output loop is within your sort loop, so it get's executed after every step of sorting. If you had your output loop directly after (not within) the sort loop, it would be executed once after the sort loop is complete. (If you use eclipse, select all of the code and press ctrl+i)

Comment: @jlordo...You guessed right..i am new on SO...i have followed your instruction but i am still confuse on what to do....I am still very new to java. thanks

Comment: This is your sort loop: `while(swapped){`. Look for the closing bracket `}` of that loop, and you'll see that your output loop `for(int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++){` is inside the sort loop. The output needs to be after the sort loop if you only want output once.